# ListView is not updating after changes to data

Tags: android, listview

I am using two `ListViews` (List1 has data and List2 is empty).

The user can enter a name as input and if List1 contains name and the add `Button` is pressed then marks should be decreased by 1 and both the `ListViews` should be updated.

**Example:**

If List1 has 10 marks and a name is entered then List1 should have marks set to 9 and List2 should have marks set to 1.

If we did this 10 times then List1 names should be removed and List2 has marks set to 10.

**Example 2:**

Suppose List1 has marks set to 8 and List2 marks set to 2. If the sub button is pressed then both should lists should be added. At this point, List2 should be deleted and List1 should have total marks as 10.

Below is the logic I have used however it is not working it is creating multiple rows and marks which not updating properly.

**HomeAct class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeAct extends Activity {

List<DocItem> docDet1 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
List<DocItem> docDet2 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
ListView lv1, lv2;
EditText editText;
Button btn1, btn2;
DocDetAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
int n=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_det1);
    lv2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_det2);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    adapter1 = new DocDetAdapter(1);
    adapter2 = new DocDetAdapter(2);

    docDet1.add(new DocItem("1", "john", 20));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("2", "james", 5));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("3", "shaun", 60));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("4", "joy", 10));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("5", "mark", 1));

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int j =0;j<docDet1.size();j++){
                final DocItem curItem = docDet1.get(j);
                if(curItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())){
                    n++;
                 DocItem docItem = docDet1.get(j);
                    docDet1.get(j).marks = n;
                    docDet2.add(0, docItem);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int j =0;j<docDet2.size();j++){
                final DocItem curItem = docDet2.get(j);
                if(curItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())){

                 DocItem docItem = docDet1.get(j);
                    docDet2.remove(j);
                    docDet1.add(0, docItem);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private class DocDetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mode; // 1 or 2

    public DocDetAdapter(int mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mode == 1)
            return docDet1.size();
        else
            return docDet2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_tray_det, null);

        TextView tvItemName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        TextView tvRack = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rack);
        TextView tvQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty);

        DocItem invItem;
        if (mode == 1)
            invItem = docDet1.get(position);
        else
            invItem = docDet2.get(position);

        tvItemName.setText(invItem.docNo);
        tvRack.setText(invItem.name);
        tvQty.setText(invItem.marks + "");

        return convertView;
        }
    }
  }
```

**DocItem class**

```
public class DocItem {

public String docNo, name;
public Integer marks;

public DocItem(String docNo, String name, Integer marks) {
    super();
    this.docNo = docNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
     }
  }
```

**home_act.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="3"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="3"
        android:text="Sub" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**row_tray_det**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
    android:id="@+id/v_doc_seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/row_bg_transparent_white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rack"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sl no"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Marks"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is an image of the expected output:**
[image: Expected Output]

In the above output, Joy had 10 marks and if "Joy" is entered as input then list should shown as above.

I could really use help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Form what i see after running your code. You eneter name john. there are two items and one of them gets updated on clicked add. Now i don't quite understand what is that you want and what is not working. Its not clear

Comment: if name has marks 10 if it is matched then marks should be decreased by 1 and added to the list2 with marks as 1 and list1 marks should be 9.

Comment: ok. But what you have is  n++; and then  `docDet1.get(j).marks = n;`. So its not clear. Can you post a snap shot what you need

Comment: ok wait. I will post.

Comment: ok. from what i understand. john marks is 20. on clicked add button it should become 19 and the same be shown in list 2. Right?

Comment: yes but list2 marks should show as 1, total marks-1 everytime if name is enetered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126711/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-nikhil).

Comment: and if list 2 already contains the same name it will update if add is cliecked again?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126716/discussion-between-nikhil-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand if the name entered in editText matches the name in the list reduce marks by 1. Add the same content to the list 2 and set marks as 1.

If you click add for the same name list 1 marks for the name reduces while marks in list2 becomes2.

Changes to be made for the add part

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DocItem changeItem = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++) {
                DocItem docItem = docDet1.get(i);
                if (docItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    changeItem = docDet1.get(i);
                    changeItem.marks = changeItem.marks - 1;
                    if (findDocItem(editText.getText().toString()) != null) {
                        DocItem docI = findDocItem(editText.getText().toString());
                        docI.marks = docI.marks + 1;
                    } else {
                        docDet2.add(new DocItem(changeItem.docNo, changeItem.name, 1));
                    }

                }

            }

            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

To find and item

```
  DocItem findDocItem(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet2) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Avoid calling `notifyDataSetChanged` inside the for loop.

You would do something similar for sub.

For the sub part from the discussion in chat

```
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int changedmarks=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < docDet2.size(); i++) {
                DocItem docItem = docDet2.get(i);
                if (docItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    changedmarks =docDet2.get(i).marks;
                    docDet2.remove(i);

                }
            }
            if(findDocItem2(editText.getText().toString())!=null )
            {
                DocItem  docitem = findDocItem2(editText.getText().toString());
                docitem.marks = docitem.marks+ changedmarks;
            }

            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Then

```
DocItem findDocItem2(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet1) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```