# If listview having same data then first row should be updated in android

Tags: android, listview

I am using two `ListViews` (List1 has data and List2 is empty).

The user can enter a name as input and if List1 contains name and the add `Button` is pressed then marks should be decreased by 1 and both the `ListViews` should be updated.

**Example:**

If List1 has 10 marks and a name is entered then List1 should have marks set to 9 and List2 should have marks set to 1.

If the list1 has same names then index with first position name should be updated. Now both the values are updated with same name.

If we did this 10 times then List1 names should be removed and List2 has marks set to 10.

**Example 2:**

Suppose List1 has marks set to 8 and List2 marks set to 2. If the sub button is pressed then both should lists should be added. At this point, List2 should be deleted and List1 should have total marks as 10.

Below is the logic I have used however it is not working it is updating multiple rows with same names.

**HomeAct class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeAct extends Activity {

List<DocItem> docDet1 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
List<DocItem> docDet2 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
ListView lv1, lv2;
EditText editText;
Button btn1, btn2;
DocDetAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
int n=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_det1);
    lv2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_det2);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    adapter1 = new DocDetAdapter(1);
    adapter2 = new DocDetAdapter(2);

    docDet1.add(new DocItem("1", "john", 20));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("2", "john", 20));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("3", "shaun", 60));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("4", "joy", 10));

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                  DocItem changeItem = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++) {
                DocItem docItem = docDet1.get(i);
                if (docItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    changeItem = docDet1.get(i);
                    changeItem.marks = changeItem.marks - 1;
                    if (findDocItem(editText.getText().toString()) != null) {
                        DocItem docI = findDocItem(editText.getText()
                                .toString());
                        docI.marks = docI.marks + 1;
                    } else {
                        docDet2.add(new DocItem(changeItem.docNo,
                                changeItem.name, 1));
                    }

                }
                                    if (docItem.marks == 0) {
                    docDet1.remove(i);
                }
            }
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



         int changedmarks=0;
             DocItem item = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < docDet2.size(); i++) {
                    DocItem docItem = docDet2.get(i);
                    item = docDet2.get(i);
                    if (docItem.name.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                        changedmarks =docDet2.get(i).marks;
                        docDet2.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                if(findDocItem2(editText.getText().toString())!=null )
                {
                    DocItem  docitem = findDocItem2(editText.getText().toString());
                    docitem.marks = docitem.marks+ changedmarks;
                }
                else{
                    System.out
                            .println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- else loop ");

                    docDet1.add(0,item);
                }

                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private class DocDetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mode; // 1 or 2

    public DocDetAdapter(int mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mode == 1)
            return docDet1.size();
        else
            return docDet2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_tray_det, null);

        TextView tvItemName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        TextView tvRack = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rack);
        TextView tvQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty);

        DocItem invItem;
        if (mode == 1)
            invItem = docDet1.get(position);
        else
            invItem = docDet2.get(position);

        tvItemName.setText(invItem.docNo);
        tvRack.setText(invItem.name);
        tvQty.setText(invItem.marks + "");

        return convertView;
        }
    }
  }
```

**DocItem class**

```
public class DocItem {

public String docNo, name;
public Integer marks;

public DocItem(String docNo, String name, Integer marks) {
    super();
    this.docNo = docNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
     }
  }
```

**home_act.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="3"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="3"
        android:text="Sub" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**row_tray_det**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
    android:id="@+id/v_doc_seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/row_bg_transparent_white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rack"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sl no"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Marks"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Starting list of data]
[image: After entering john and add button is pressed 1 time then list should be updated]
[image: After entering john and add button is pressed 5 times then list should be updated]
[image: [![After entering john and sub button is pressed 1 time then list should be updated]
[image: After entering john and add button is pressed 21 times then list should be updated]
[image: After entering john and sub button is pressed 1 time then list should be updated]
I could really use help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What requirement changes from answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259598/listview-is-not-updating-after-changes-to-data

Comment: If same name is there twice then need to update the first position of matched name, now it is updating both the both the name values.

Comment: same name in list1? You need associate a unique id for the names. that would be easier to track.

Comment: Yes sir, we have id as 1,2,3...

Comment: how do you know that names that you type is associated with 1,2 or 3? bcoz ur search is baaed on name. and not index

Comment: if we type name then we will get position of that name based on that we need to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127154/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-nikhil).